# Finding CPU utilization and CPU cycles

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cpu-usage, profiler

My program is in C++ and I have one server listening to a number of clients. Clients send small packets to server. I'm running my code on Ubuntu.

I want to measure the CPU utilization and possibly total number of CPU cycles on both sides, ideally with a breakdown on cycles/utilization spent on networking (all the way from NIC to the user space and vice versa), kernel space, user space, context switches, etc.

I did some search, but I couldn't figure out whether it should be done inside my C++ code or an external profiler should be used, or perhaps some other way.

Comment: Have a look at SystemTap. https://sourceware.org/systemtap/

Comment: Please edit your question to motivate it. Why do you ask? Why common profiling & benchmarking techniques are not enough? What exactly did you try?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think I motivated it enough in my question (the second paragraph). If by common profiling you mean information retrievable from /proc, then it does not give detailed cost breakdown for networking/....

Comment: No, I was referring to `oprofile`

Answer (score 1):

Your best friend/helper in this case is the `/proc` file system in Linux. In `/proc` you will find CPU usage, memory usage, power usage etc. Have a look at this link

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

Even you can check each process cpu usage by looking at the files `/proc/`*process_id*`/stat`.

Comment: Also, a process can query its own status using `/proc/self/stat`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you both for the tip. However, as far as I know, /proc is considered course-grained profiling and does not give detailed information about cpu cycles and also how it's distributed among networking/user space/etc, right?

Comment: You could perhaps use `oprofile`; but please explain exactly why do you ask, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the RDTSCP instruction and some other ways to measure performacnce [metrics](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf). System simulators like SniperSim, Gem5 etc. can also give total cycle count of your running program ( however, they may not be very accurate - there are some conditions that need to be met (core frequencies are same etc.))

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you probably should consider using [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/). I am not very familiar with it (and it may be complex to use, and require system-wide configuration)